# Bash completion won't work if calling application with the absolute path

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Not knowing why, but the bash completion won't work if I call application in the absolute path.

For example, I have file1 & file2 under the current directory

```
[zhengw@localhost ~]$ rm -f file<tab><tab>
file1  file2
[zhengw@localhost ~]$ which rm
/bin/rm
[zhengw@localhost ~]$ /bin/rm -f file<tab><tab>
```

In the above example, bash auto completed the files for me in the first command, but returned nothing for the second command.

Also tried other commands, it turns out if I use the absolute path, the bash completion just won't work.

Comment: You didn't delete file1 & file2 before running second command?

Comment: Which distribution, version and kernel version do you use?

Comment: CentOS 6.6, Bash v4.1.2. Note this is a company IT distributed vm, not knowing any customization they might have done to it.

Comment: No, I didn't delete those files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've nailed the root cause. I installed the fzf application for my vim to use its' fuzzy searching function. The default installation method of fzf vim plugin installed a bash completion script which was sourced into the bashrc file, and it eventually messed up with the original completion function.

I was able to fix the problem by uninstall the plugin, and reinstall it with --bin option.

Solution:

Change the install method of fzf plugin(in your .vimrc) from:

```
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', {'dir': '~/.fzf', 'do': './install --all' }
```

to:

```
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', {'dir': '~/.fzf', 'do': './install --bin' }
```

Comment: My experience with bash completion scripts is that they are well intentioned but typically so broken and unpredictable in practice that I just disable them completely. E.g. many of them disable filename completion in contexts where you want to enter a filename.

Comment: Hi Wayne, you should accept this answer (click on the check mark) so that the question is marked as *answered*.